# Potential mistake in a textbook? Is $y=x^{1/2}$ the same as $y=±\sqrt{x}$?

Tags: functions, radicals

So I was consulting a textbook ([Stroud, K. A., & Booth, D. J. (2009). Foundation mathematics](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Foundation-Mathematics-K-Stroud/dp/0230579078)) for some definitions and noticed the following statement on p. 275:

> $y=x^{1/2}$ which is the same as $y=±\sqrt{x}$

I am confused as I have always thought that $f(x)=y=x^{1/2} = \sqrt{x}$. Am I wrong or is that a mistake in the textbook?

[image: Foundation Mathematics, p. 275]

Comment: "$y^2= x$" was probably meant. It is most likely a "typo".

Comment: Yes, the expression $x^{1/2}$ is practically always used to denote the principal (positive) root, $+\sqrt{x}$. The excerpt would be better written as "$y=\pm x^{1/2}$ which is . . ."

Comment: As long as we are in the reals , in $x^{1/2}$ , $x$ must be non-negative and then, $x^{1/2}$ is the same as $\sqrt{x}$ , so the textbook is clearly wrong.